# Connecting a 6 pole motor to a motor driver?

Tags: brushless-motor, driver

We are trying to power [this motor](http://www.e-fliterc.com/Products/Default.aspx?ProdID=EFLM3032DFA) with [this motor driver](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/vnh2sp30-motor-driver-carrier-md01b-p-228.html) , using a 11.1V 2.2Ah lithium-ion polymer battery.

(We're in over our heads with this and really need the help)

We checked with the company (E-flite) and the motor is definitely DC -- we're a bit confused as to the purpose of three wires, and how we should connect them to the motor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No need for the long thank you -- it [adds to the noise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) (I've removed it). Your upvotes/acceptance tick are good enough thankyous for us -- and the existence of your question helps the site grow; thank _you_. And welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange :)

Answer (score 2):

The motor you have there is a Brushless DC motor. It's still technically a DC motor, but you won't be able to drive it by plugging it into a battery, or even into the driver you linked to. You need a driver specifically for brushless motors that can drive all three wires correctly.

[image: Brushless motor driver]]

Something like this [Electronic Speed Controller](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/electronic-speed-controller-p-716.html) will drive it pretty well:

[image: Electronic speed controller]

You connect the motor to the 3 wires, and the power to the two wires. The little 3-wire connector normally goes to a Radio Control (RC) receiver, plugging into the servo socket. It accepts a PWM signal just like a normal servo.

Comment: What if we really really really wanted to use this motor driver?

Alternatively, what if we used the ESC, but wanted them controlled by a PI or Arduino or beagle board or something (Not RC). How would we do that?

Comment: You either need to change the motor to a *Brushed* DC motor. Or you need to change the motor driver to a *Brushless* motor driver. You could easily drive the ESC from an Arduino. It just needs a [PWM signal](http://www.brookshiresoftware.com/rd_how_servos_work.htm).

Comment: To re-itterate what rocketmagnet said, you listed a brushless motor (3wire) and a brushed speed controller (2wire) - they both need to be brushed or brushless. Both versions (brushed or brushless) need PWM signals to operate, which an arduino can easily provide.

Comment: Okay thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For the benefit of myself and future readers, can someone explain the difference between Brushed & Brushless motors, why are there a different number of wires?